# KeePass - Google drive direct vs GoogleSync Plugin

Tags: android, google-drive-api, synchronization, keepass

I am using KeePass v2 and I am a bit confused about synchronizing the kbdx file on google drive.   There seems to be two ways and not sure what the advantages/disadvantages are between them.

1. Using the KPGoogleSync plugin
2. Store the kdbx on the Google sync folder (C:\users\xxx\Google Drive)

It doesn't seem that either one can detect changes that were made by a mobile device and automatically load them in.  Both methods seem to require open and closing of the database in order to get the most recent changes done externally.   The plugin does seem to have a menu based way of performing the update as well.

So what benefit would there be to use one versus the other that I am missing?  I am most worried about the sync process and losing data between desktop and mobile device.   Is one preferred over the other?

Answer (score 0):

The sync plugin can handle simultaneous changes on both sides of the sync.

It merges the databases when syncing by knowing the structure and change dates of each entry in the key database.

Using the external sync tool, this merge is not possibly since the tool can not know the structure and the encyrption key of the database.